# Search Engine with spiders

Tags: php, asp.net, search-engine

I need to write a small search engine with spiders and all this stuff.What do you recommend men ASP.NET or PHP ? 
and what sources should i read in to get the knowledge?

Comment: I'd recommend, first of all, coming up with a theory of how to create your search engine, its objectives and the means of execution. Then I'd suggest reading around those areas. 'And all this stuff' doesn't really help us to understand your objectives, needs or question.

Comment: i would like to gather images using my search engine to apply an algorithm to find images using image as input

Answer (score 4):

Before you begin writing this monster of a project (by no means will it be small) I'd like to know *why* you need to write this engine... Is it for an internal project that can't be indexed by other search engines, or what?

If it's a search engine for a site of your own which you have full control of, it's better to index the information on the site as it's added, edited, and removed, to prevent having to use spiders.

If it's for other websites, then the technology that engines such as Google, Yahoo, and Bing have to offer will always be better than what you can come up with in a couple weeks. If it's something that they can index, then I'd suggest looking into their APIs (Bing has some pretty neat ones if you are okay with the results they provide) and use them for crawling and querying whatever you require them to.

If you really *need* to make your own engine, it's not going to be a small project..

Comment: i would like to gather images using my search engine to apply an algorithm to find images using image as input

Comment: Well if you're matching images based on an algorithm, then you should first write a script that will recurse through all the 'searchable' images on your server and apply the same algorithm to them, indexing them in a DB as it goes along.

Then when the user inputs an image, you can run the algorithm on the image and match it to the results of the indexed images. I don't know what type of algorithm you're going to apply, but that would be the general concept...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write it, I recommend you: [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/)